# To Chnage Nuxeo Login Properties

Tags: email, ldap, single-sign-on, cas, nuxeo

I am newer to Nuxeo. I had successfully implemented SSO with LDAP-CAS-NUXEO, but Nuxeo takes login credentials as UserName & Password. But I want to change it to Email & password. I am not able to find any way to do it. Any help in this will be greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using LDAP and CAS you just need to change one Property in default-ldap-users-directory-config.xml.

```
<extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.directory.ldap.LDAPDirectoryFactory"
point="directories">
<directory name="userDirectory">
  <server>default</server>
  <schema>user</schema>
  <idField>username</idField>
  <passwordField>password</passwordField>
```

.....

here in `<idField>` you can use **email** instead of username.

Comment: Thanks Prakash for your help, this has resolved my issue :-)